# Java Expect "{" error dont understand

Tags: java

These code gives

> error message "Main.java:3: error: '{' expected public  class 
>   Bister.java {

```
               1 error"
```

I can't understand "why is come up ?" .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bister.java  {         
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input first number: ");
        int num1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input second number: ");
        int num2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num1 + " x " + num2 + " = " + num1 * num2);
     }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove .java in source code. change below line

```
 public class Bister.java {
```

like this

```
 public class Bister {
```

Your code will be like

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bister {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Input first number: "); 
 int num1 = in.nextInt();

System.out.print("Input second number: "); 
int num2 = in.nextInt();

System.out.println(num1 + " x " + num2 + " = " + num1 * num2); }

}
```

Comment: java will put error then needs a file .java  , how to resolve that error as well ?

Comment: save your file with the extension .java, you no need to put extension to the class name in source code.

Comment: [b] Main.java:3: error: class Bister is public, should be declared in a file named Bister.java
public class Bister { [/b]   I'm using online java compiler . Maybe is that problem.

Comment: @Powiux `public ClassName {...}` needs to be placed in `ClassName.java` file (this should be explained at start of any decent Java tutorial, if it wasn't then either you didn't start reading from beginning or it wasn't good tutorial/book)

Comment: .java is your file type, save it as Bister.java

Comment: Source Code can contain any number of classes, but you have to save your file as the name of the class(.java) which is having public static void main(String[] args){} method.

Comment: @BalayesuChilakalapudi "you have to save your file as the name of the class(.java) which is having public static void main(String[] args){} method" that is incorrect, you can have one `.java` file with many classes, and each of those class can have its own *main* method. Only limitation is that `.java` file must have same name as `public class` (or any other public type like interface, enum) which it holds.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the file `Main.java`, it should contain `public class Main {`.
If you want it to be `public class Bister {`, the file has to be `Bister.java`
And the `.java` appears in the filename only, it is not part of the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

Remove .java in class name
Current code: public class Bister.java
Update to   : public class Bister

Also your file name should be "Bister.java".